# Laravel Relationships Between Two Models

Tags: php, laravel

I am struggling with working with relationships right now and would like some help as for how to make this relationship work. I am using Laravel.

Lets say you have a staff model that looks like so:

Staff.php

```
class Staff extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Staff_status');
    }
}
```

The database table for the staff is as follows:

```
Table Name: staff
Fields: id, staffer_name, status_id
```

You also have a staff status model represented below:

Staff_statuses.php

```
class Staff_status extends Eloquent {

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Staff');
    } 

}
```

You also have a staff database table like so:

```
Table Name: staff_statuses
Fields: id, status_name
```

However when I try and load the staff controller index method it says class Staff_status is not found.

Any idea why?

Comment: might this problem be related to a file name issue? what about if you rename the class to Staff_statuses? (exactly as you named the php file)

Comment: I'm sorry I am using Laravel I forgot to mention that but it is in the tags anyway.

Comment: sorry, i edited my comment as you already said it in the title, i don't know Laravel, but i have experience with other frameworks. Check if it's a filename -> classname issue.

Comment: I have checked and verified that it is not an issue with file name and class name naming conventions.

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: I still don't have anything working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `Staff_statuses.php` as the name of your `model` but you are using `Staff_status` in the class name and thus you are calling it using `Staff_status` from your controller as well. This is the problem.

Change the file name to match the `class name`. For example, use something like this:

```
// StaffStatus.php
class StaffStatus extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'staff_statuses';

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Staff');
    } 
}

// Staff.php
class Staff extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'staff';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('StaffStatus');
    }
}
```

In the `controller` you may use something like this:

```
$staffStatus = StaffStatus::all();
$staff = Staff::all();
```

Comment: That's great however and for some reason I put staff_statuses.php when it is staff_status.php and you will that correct the relationship issue?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I still receive the same error.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Its getting no relationship when I dd($staff) for each staffer. So I'm wondering if its not understanding that the field that needs to see as being the key is the status_id or not.

Comment: I'm trying to access $staffer->status->name when I do my foreach loop in my HTML. I understand the error I'm getting but not sure why its not making the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{

```
public function imageable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

}

class Staff extends Model
{

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Photo', 'imageable');
}
```

}

class Product extends Model
{

```
public function photos()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Photo', 'imageable');
}
```

}